# No indent for Feed's "A" icon block

Tags: bug, design, android-app

Some items in the Feed contain the answer icon shown by the letter A in a speech bubble.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Such icon and number should have indent from the right.

Also question's title should have nicer word wrapping (needs indent too). See the 1st picture.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (1635123498b3d)

Comment: The title problem could be fixed by shortening the length the title can get to before wrapping.