# Answer count on feed items is wrong

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed, multiple-answers

In my feed under the earlier today section, I saw a hot question from one of the sites I was on, and it had one answer. After posting an answer, the answer count on the feed item remained at one.

> [image: Feed item, answer count appears to be 1]

On the post, the count is correct:

> [image: Answer count on the question, shows as 2]

Either the feed does not update to show when a question's answer count has increased, or it does not update if the answer is provided by the user who is using the app.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LGLS992
- OS Version: 7.0 (180320959b773)

Comment: Have you refreshed the feed by pulling it down? If you only pressing the back button to return to the feed after posting the answer, then the feed won't be updated automatically (aka caching, possibly to reduce data usage). Note that the feed also only periodically (not always) updates when starting the app for the same reason.

Comment: @Somewhat I refreshed the feed multiple times. I will try restarting the app.

Comment: @Somewhat The answer count is fixed now, but I restarted the app and the phone since I noticed this for unrelated reasons. It is fine now, but I can't say for sure what fixed it.

Comment: Related [design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289991/339911) issue.